# Transmission - Poor Shifting - Next Steps

Tags: automatic-transmission, mazda, mazda-6

My transmission shifts poorly most of the time.  The poor shifting feels like when you manually shift to a lower gear when at speed. The shifting is far from violent and has no audible noise.  The issue is only shifting.  Each gear runs smoothly.  The car otherwise runs fine.

A local auto repair shop replaced the fluid, replaced gaskets, and cleaned the magnet.  This may have helped somewhat, but the issue definitely remains. They stated there was no CARFAX record of a previous fluid change. The vehicle has otherwise been serviced by the dealership since I got it at 45,000 miles a few years ago.

I have a Transmission Diagnosis appointment with the dealership in a couple weeks.  I scheduled this appointment before I found a shop which could get me in sooner for a diagnosis.

**Vehicle:** 2018 Mazda 6 Touring, automatic transmission, 93,000 miles

**Questions**

1. How critical is it to repair or replace the transmission soon?   Is it likely to get worse over time or fail quickly at any time?
2. What do you recommend for next steps: dealership diagnosis, transmission repair, transmission replacement, or new car?
3. Should I consider a recycled transmission?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!